# Devolver True o False dependiendo si ha insertado o no un valor en la tabla PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando una serie de ejercicios con **PLSQL** y la verdad que acabo de estancarme en uno que dice así:

> Crear una función que añada una nueva marca recibida y devuelva true o false, dependiendo de si la ha insertado en la tabla o no. Tener en cuenta que no se insertará si el nombre ya está en la tabla.

He hecho esta parte de código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION introducirMarca(vcifm NUMBER, vnombre VARCHAR(30), vciudad 
VARCHAR(30)) return boolean
IS
cursor buscar IS select nombre from marca where nombre = vnombre;
busqueda marca.nombre%TYPE;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO marca VALUES (vcifm, vnombre, vciudad);
open buscar;
fetch buscar INTO busqueda;
END;
```

La idea es utilizar un bucle para que vaya recorriendo el cursor y si encuentra un registro igual a los introducidos por parámetros en la función, que devuelva **True** y sino pues **False**.

Pero estoy empezando con esto desde hace poco y no se muy bien como seguir... Si alguien puede ayudar, lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: te recomiendo que formatees correctamente el código, no es cómodo de leer

Comment: Cierto, no me fijè. Editado. Gracias.

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos?

Comment: @anonimo plsql es Oracle

Comment: lo pregunte @NickolasGarcia para que se agregue dicha etiqueta pues el OP no lo hizo y eso ayudaría a clasificar mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma en como lo planteas es poco eficiente, lo mejor que podrías hacer seria colocar un indice único a nivel de la columna que deseas que sea única, y de esa forma podrías manejar la excepción de violación de indice único a nivel de tu función de la siguiente forma:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION introducirMarca (
  vcifm   NUMBER
, vnombre VARCHAR(30)
, vciudad VARCHAR(30)) RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
  INSERT INTO marca VALUES (vcifm, vnombre, vciudad);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Comment: esto esta bien escrito? `RUTURN` ?

Comment: @anonimo ya está corregido